# Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x+i)}{x^2+1} \text{d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

The first part of the question asks to define a branch of $\log(z+i)$ which is holomorphic in the cut-plane $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{z : \text{Re} (z) = 0, \text{Im}(z) ≤ -1\}$. I've defined this as $\log(r)+i\theta$ with $z + i = re^{i\theta}$, $r>0$ and $\theta \in (-\pi/2, 3\pi/2)$.

The next part of the questions asks: by integrating $\log(z+i)/(z^2+1)$ around a suitable closed path, evaluate
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\log(x+i)}{x^2+1} \text{d}x. $$

I think I'm meant to integrate along a semicircle of radius $R$, then subtract the integral along the arc of the semicircle and taking $R \to \infty$. Using the residue theorem, I've calculated the residue at $z=i$ to be $\log(2i)/2i$, so the integral along the semicircle is $\pi\log(2i)$. My question is, how am I meant to integrate along the arc? I suspect that it goes to 0, but I can't seem to find why.

Comment: Denoting $C_R$ the arch (of the radius $R$) in the upper half-plane
$$\left|\int_{C_R}\frac{\log(z+i)}{z^2+1}dz\right|=\left|\int_0^\pi\frac{\log(Re^{i\phi}+i)}{R^2e^{2i\phi}+1}iRe^{i\phi}d\phi\right|<\int_0^\pi\left|\frac{\log(Re^{i\phi}+i)}{R^2e^{2i\phi}+1}iRe^{i\phi}\right|d\phi$$

Comment: $$=\int_0^\pi\frac{|\log\big(R\cos\phi+i(1+R\sin\phi)\big)|}{\sqrt{(R^2\cos(2\phi)+1)^2+R^4\sin^2(2\phi)}}Rd\phi<\int_0^\pi\frac{\log\big|R\cos\phi+i(1+R\sin\phi)\big|}{\sqrt{R^4+1+2R^2\cos(2\phi)}}Rd\phi$$
$$<\frac{R\log(R+1)}{R^2-1}\int_0^\pi d\phi\to 0\,\,\text{at}\,\,R\to\infty$$